# javascript | regex search URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a script below:

```
<script src="http://localhost/folder/api/v1/shop/1?template=light" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And need regular expression to detect this block:  `api/v{1-any number}/shop/{1-any number}`

For example regular expression for this block: shop.load.v1.php :

```
/.*shop\.load\.([^/]+\.)?php/
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you mentioned the regex for `shop.load.v1.php`? What does it have to do with detecting the block `api/v{1-any number}/shop/{1-any number}`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this pattern:

```
/api\/v(\d+)\/shop\/(\d+)/
```

It will match a literal `api/v` followed by one or more digits, followed by a literal `/shop/` followed by one or more digits.

But this will match text like `api/v00/shop/00`. If you'd like to ensure the matched number is  greater than or equal to 1, you can use this:

```
/api\/v([1-9]\d*)\/shop\/([1-9]\d*)/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`/api/v[1-9]{1}\/shop\/[1-9]{1}/`

This is if it can have only a single digit. For multiple digits:

`/api/v[1-9]+\/shop\/[1-9]+/`